# ionic 3 events not publishing . Need to publish data to show data in sidemnu

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I need to pass data to sidemenu of app . when i am login i am publishing the event but but nothing happen.

.ts

```
 signin(){
  //signin code here
  this.events.publish('user:created', {data:res.UserName});
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(FrontPage, {x:res.Cardnumber});
 }
```

app.component.ts

```
 this.events.subscribe('user:loggedIn',(data)=>{      
  console.log('login event recieved'+ data);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this Bcoz in your code you pass wrong event name

```
signin(){
  this.events.publish('user:created', YourArryPassHere);
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(FrontPage, {x:res.Cardnumber});
}

this.events.subscribe('user:created',(data)=>{
   // You get your array here      
   console.log('login event recieved'+ data);
})
```

Comment: yes it works . but can you tell me how to pass array ? because when im passing single object its showing but when i am passing array data its not showing in component.ts just showing object liek this login event recieved[object Object]